# Vue 3 Application redirects to main domain from subdirectory and routes failed to work

Tags: javascript, apache, vue.js, vue-router, single-page-application

can somebody suggest to me what is going wrong with my application here? I have a vue 3 SPA. I'm hosting it here for like

```
example.com/subdirectory/myapp/
```

It redirects to example.com after loading the app from the same path

```
example.com - redirected here with routes e.g example.com/create or example.com/delete
```

What I want to achieve is loading all routes from the subdirectory path like

```
example.com/subdirectory/myapp/create
example.com/subdirectory/myapp/delete
```

etc.

My vue.config.js code is as below:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: './',
};
```

My Routes code is as below:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter} from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
    {path: '/', name: 'list', component: () => import('@/views/List')},
    {path: '/create', name: 'create', component: () => import('@/views/Create')},
    {path: '/delete', name: 'delete', component: () => import('@/views/Delete')},
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

Please guide me what is something wrong I'm doing here? I'm guessing it's something with my routing config for apache serving but what is that? I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Try setting `publicPath` to a single dot with no slashes - or even better, to the full path to your app, e.g. `/subdirectory/myapp`. Also, make sure to set exactly the same value for the argument `base` of your VueRouter - https://router.vuejs.org/api/#parameters-1

Comment: Oh man - You are rock star.